# Fastest way to create a json object by template in ASP.NET Core Api

Tags: c#, json, templates, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET core Api, which is responsible to retrieve a data from another Api and put it in a specific data structure and return it as a json object.

The data and the data structure could be vary based on the api input parameters.

So I'm thinking to use template base programming to return back the json object. What I needed is adding new template without building the project. So i need run-time base template

What I'm trying to do is:

```
var data = await GetDataFromDataSources(request);
var template = FetchTemplate(request);

return GenerateObject(data, template);
```

For binding data to template I tried different options:

- [StringTemplate](https://www.stringtemplate.org/)
- [RazorEngine](https://github.com/fouadmess/RazorEngine)

Each of them have pros and cons

StringTemplate has special syntax and limited to that syntax

RazorEngine is good for html but I have to make it for json.

The data I received isa  dynamic object, I don't have any idea what it could looks like in compile time.

What is the best option for this purpose? Performance is matter and flexibility. any idea?

Comment: How dynamic do these templates actually need to be. Rather than explicitly serializing to JSON I usually build something out of dictionaries or dynamics and let the implicit serializer take care of turning it into Content-Type. If you are working with ADO.NET you can directly build Dictionary or Expando objects from a result set and simply altering the DB view you query can alter the data returned from the middle tier with no rebuilds.

Comment: @ChrisBecke, Let's say I just make it simple in question actually I call the api to fetch the data I don't have any control on that